Rollup failed to resolve import "Leaflet"
Please help me, I use this plugin in my new Vue 3 + TS project https://github.com/nypl-spacetime/Leaflet.GeotagPhoto
I previously used this plugin on vanilla JS + Laravel here ( https://github.com/Catkitkatars/RoadLens ) connected it like this - import 'leaflet-geotag-photo'; After that, I did the assembly using VITE. And the plugin worked successfully in the project. But now, for some reason, Vite gives an error - Roll up failed to resolve import "Leaflet" from "/app/node_modules/leaflet-geotag-photo/index.js ". And I can't figure out how to fix the error...
I tried using aliases in vite. alias:
vite.config.ts:

{
'@': '@': file URL To Path(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
'Leaflet': 'node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js',
}

This solved the problem with building the project, but the plugin never worked.
